# Check PowerState of Azure VM inside of Azure Policy

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I'm working on an Azure Policy to audit running VMs with a custom tag which indicates that the VM is assumed to be decomissioned. The PowerState of the VM is not a normal ARM Attribute but you can find information about the State in the instanceView of the VM:

```
{
  "vmAgent": {
    "vmAgentVersion": "2.7.41491.1008",
    "statuses": [
      {
        "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
        "level": "Info",
        "displayStatus": "Ready",
        "message": "GuestAgent is running and processing the extensions.",
        "time": "2021-03-17T08:29:33+00:00"
      }
    ]
  },
  "disks": [
    {
      "name": "DecomissionedVM_OsDisk_1_cfeff76df794480383af685c6062e9b9",
      "statuses": [
        {
          "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
          "level": "Info",
          "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
          "time": "2021-03-17T08:09:56.3998144+00:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bootDiagnostics": {},
  "statuses": [
    {
      "code": "ProvisioningState/succeeded",
      "level": "Info",
      "displayStatus": "Provisioning succeeded",
      "time": "2021-03-17T08:10:06.4623615+00:00"
    },
    {
      "code": "PowerState/running",
      "level": "Info",
      "displayStatus": "VM running"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is also a valid Alias for the StatusCode which can be used to create a policy definition:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2018-05-01/subscriptionDeploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "variables": {
        "policyName": "restrict-startup-of-decomissioned-vms",
        "policyDisplayName": "Restrict startup of decomissioned VMs",
        "policyDescription": "Restrict startup of VMs with 'decomissioned' tag"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
            "name": "[variables('policyName')]",
            "apiVersion": "2019-09-01",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "[variables('policyDisplayName')]",
                "policyType": "Custom",
                "description": "[variables('policyDescription')]",
                "metadata": {
                    "category": "General"
                },
                "mode": "All",
                "policyRule": {
                    "if": {
                        "allOf": [{
                                "field": "type",
                                "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/instanceView.statuses[*].code",
                                "contains": "PowerState/running"
                            },
                            {
                                "field": "tags[decomissioned]",
                                "exists": "true"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "effect": "audit"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The creation and assignment of the policy works, but running machines with the decomissioned tag are not marked as not compliant.

Does anyone know how to correctly use the Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/instanceView.statuses[*].code field?

Answer (score 0):

We are not able to use alias: Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/instanceView.statuses[*].code since the property would not be returned when the policy sent GET call to the VM.

Here is more details:https://github.com/Azure/azure-policy#resource-type-query-results-incomplete-missing-or-non-standard-format

*"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/instanceView
Collection query of this type is missing many properties, which means compliance checks may not work."*